# Paste letter grades B+ , C-, A, B into notebook and not get B+C-AB

Tags: string-manipulation

I have worked for two days to find a way through this problem.

I am porting my student grade records into *Mathematica* from spreadsheets, or sometimes from my college web sites, or sometimes from my word processor. I have many different source formats as you see, but I find I can always get the data into the format where it will paste into a word processor in one or the other format sketched in my subject line above.

I can deal with the *Mathematica* end of the project once the grades are in the form `List["B+", "C-", "A", "B"]` -- from there convert them into gpa's, points, sums, averages, whatever -- but I have not been able to operate on the data Pasted into *Mathematica* because the pluses and minuses are interpreted as parts of incomplete expressions, which blocks execution of string functions.

To get the data in, I need to use use the Windows Copy command, then Paste into *Mathematica*.  The source can easily be one of the two character formats shown just below.  (Or see my subject line.)  But unfortunately the grades often have pluses and minuses, especially B+ or C+.

But if I paste the following example straight into List in an Input cell, it is interpreted as an incomplete expression:

```
List[D+, F , C-, F, A-, B, A, A- ,D-, B-, C-, B, D-, D, B, D, A+, B, D, B+, F, C-, F, C+, D-, D+, B]
```

The same thing happens if I paste the same information in this way:

```
List[D + F C - F A - B A A - D - B - C - B D - D B D A + B D B + F C - F C + D - D + B]
```

So I need a "container" to paste into, which will eliminate white spaces, attach any pluses or minuses to the preceding character, and interpret each letter grade as a string as here: `List["B+", "C-", "A", "B"]` (By the way the only letters which appear are ABCDFWI, if that permits simplification, and the only non-letters are + and -).

I feel kinda dumb asking about this, but Strings in *Mathematica* are so crazy I'm just not there yet.

Comment: Why not just Import the Excel file directly into Mathematica? You get an array identical to that in your spreadsheet.

Comment: Some grades are copied and pasted from a university website, also my spreadsheets are so large, with so many sheets and formulas and cells without data, that my computers all hang when I attempt the Import.  This is an issue I may give to the stackExchange at some point....

Answer (score 8):

If you paste your expression as a string, this should work:

```
s = "D+,F,C-,F,A-,B,A,A-,D-,B-,C-,B,D-,D,B,D,A+,B,D,B+,F,C-,F,C+,D-,D+,B";

StringSplit[s, ","]
```

> {"D+", "F", "C-", "F", "A-", "B", "A", "A-", "D-", "B-", "C-", "B", "D-", 
>        "D", "B", "D", "A+", "B", "D", "B+", "F", "C-", "F", "C+", "D-", "D+", 
>        "B"}

Comment: This worked.  Thanks.  My mistake was thinking that String[A+C-DDF,A] would CREATE a string out of the sequence, create "A+C-DDF,A".  I now see String doesn't do this.  String is not like Plus, or Plot, it is like Symbol.  It's just a Head.  Now I wonder if there IS a function which would create a string out of A+C-DDF,A.  Not immediately relevant to my situation, but just curious.